# c# check for datetime not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datetime

I am creating my own DateTime class within C# and for some reason my checks are not working. When I run the program and enter a date it always stops and reaches the last line which is on the "Day" method and says "ArgumentOutOfException. Is there anyway to solve this issue and to make my checks called "Value" working?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace date
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\tNextDate Application\n\t\t\t\t\t-------------------------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("please enter date as dd/MM/yyyy");
            int day;
            int month;
            int year;

            string[] read = Console.ReadLine().Split('/');
            day = int.Parse(read[0]);
            month = int.Parse(read[1]);
            year = int.Parse(read[2]);

            Date date = new Date(day, month, year);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", date.Day, date.Month, date.Year);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class Date
        {
            private int _month; // 1-12
            private int _day; // 1-31 depending on month
            private int _year;

            public Date(int day, int month, int year)
            {
                Day = day;
                Month = month;
                Year = year;
            }

            public int Year
            {
                get { return _year; }
                set
                {
                    if (value >= 1820 && value <= 2020)
                        _year = value;
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("year", value, "year out of range");
                }
            }

            public int Month
            {
                get { return _month; }
                set
                {
                    if (value > 0 && value <= 12)
                        _month = value;
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Month", value, "Month must be 1-12");
                }
            }

            public int Day
            {
                get { return _day; }
                set
                {

                    int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

                    if (value > 0 && value <= days[_month])
                        _day = value;

                    else if (_month == 2 && value == 29 &&
                        _year % 400 == 0 || (_year % 4 == 0 && _year % 100 != 0))
                        _day = value;
                    else
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Day", value, "Day is out of range");



                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't really debug your application for you.  You're explicitly throwing that exception if certain conditions are not met.  Therefore it would appear that those conditions are not being met.  Step through your code in a debugger and examine the runtime values.  What are those values when the exception is thrown?

Comment: I am inputting 03/03/2012 for example. I have tried many different dates

Comment: you need to use `DateTime.ParseExact` function do you need an example on how to use it..?

Comment: I do not want to use DateTime at all, as I am creating my own DateTime class

Comment: why are you re-inventing the wheel..?

Comment: `var someDate2 = "03/03/2012";
 DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(someDate2, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));`

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are assigning `day` before `month`, so the second condition of your `if` and `else-if` won't work correctly. Learn to use a break point and step through your code.

Comment: Another trap to consider:  You can change the month and end up with an invalid date without any way to prevent it.  One way to fix that is to make the class immutable and only validate in the constructor (or factory method) after ALL values are set.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you do in your constructor is set the `Day` property:

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year)
{
    Day = day;
    Month = month;
    Year = year;
}
```

What does that setter *do*?  A lot, it seems.  Specifically, first it checks this:

```
if (value > 0 && value <= days[_month])
```

For your given input (in a comment above), `value` is `3`.  `3 > 0` is true, so that's ok.  But `3` is not `<= 0`.  And `days[_month]` is `0` at this time.  So this condition is false.

Your next condition is:

```
else if (_month == 2 && value == 29 &&
```

This is also false, since `_month` is currently `0` (and `value` is `3`).

So then what does your method do?  This:

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Day", value, "Day is out of range");
```

Which explains why you're getting an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.  When you throw an exception, that exception is, well, thrown.

---

It *seems* like you want to set `Day` *last* in your constructor:

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year)
{
    Year = year;
    Month = month;
    Day = day;
}
```

Though having so much hidden dependencies between your values probably should be addressed at a higher logical level as well.

Answer (score 5):

In your constructor:

> ```
> public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
>   Day = day;
>   Month = month;
>   Year = year;
> }
> ```

you assigned the `Day` property first. At this point `Month` will be default initialised – to zero – but the checks in the `Day` setter assume `Month` has been set. So the days in the month value will be 0.

You need to rethink how you do this. Probably better is to not use automatic properties so you can set the fields and then validate the date as a whole.

Reserve setters and validation there to the external interface.

Even better would be to make it an imutable value type.

Better still would be to not re-invent the wheel (unless you have very [good reason](http://nodatime.org/)).

Comment: exactly what my point is OP is trying to re-invent the wheel when they should be understanding the DateTime class and it's powerful methods / functions

Comment: Another vote for don't re-invent the wheel

Comment: What about "please enter date as dd/MM/yyyy"?

Comment: @Morpheus you are right. OP please dont reinvent the Wheel. I use c# more than 8 years and never need to do this..

Comment: @IgorQuirino What about it? It has nothing – as far as I can see – to do with any argument exceptions.

Comment: @Richard mimimi bla bla bla la la la. You are not right...

Comment: @IgorQuirino You're going to need to say why clearly,

Answer (score -2):

`Date` constructor using _month before assign. Assign Month before Day. You need to change Date constructor as follows.

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year)
{
   Month = month;             
   Day = day;
   Year = year;
}
```