# c# out of range errors

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datetime

I have created my own DateTime class and it seems to be working. I was just wondering how can I print errors within my console for my ArgumentOutOfRangeExceptions? I am unsure how to do this so I would like some help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace date
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\tNextDate Application\n\t\t\t\t\t-------------------------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("please enter date as dd/MM/yyyy");
            int day;
            int month;
            int year;

            string[] read = Console.ReadLine().Split('/');
            day = int.Parse(read[0]);
            month = int.Parse(read[1]);
            year = int.Parse(read[2]);

            Date date = new Date(day, month, year);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", date.Day, date.Month, date.Year);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class Date
        {
            private int _month; // 1-12
            private int _day; // 1-31 depending on month
            private int _year;

            public Date(int day, int month, int year)
            {
                Month = month;
                Day = day;         
                Year = year;
            }

            public int Year
            {
                get { return _year; }
                set
                {
                    if (value >= 1820 && value <= 2020)
                        _year = value;
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("year", value, "year out of range");
                }
            }

            public int Month
            {
                get { return _month; }
                set
                {
                    if (value > 0 && value <= 12)
                        _month = value;
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Month", value, "Month must be 1-12");
                }
            }

            public int Day
            {
                get { return _day; }
                set
                {

                    int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

                    if (value > 0 && value <= days[_month])
                        _day = value;

                    else if (_month == 2 && value == 29 &&
                        _year % 400 == 0 || (_year % 4 == 0 && _year % 100 != 0))
                        _day = value;
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Day", value, "Day is out of range");


                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# check for datetime not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790046/c-sharp-check-for-datetime-not-working)

Comment: Oh, it's not _exactly_ the same question, but the same _bunch of code_, nevermind.

Comment: Why have you implemented your own Date class? Assignment?

Answer (score 4):

simply catch the exceptions you throw

```
try
{
    Date date = new Date(day, month, year);
}
catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}
```

also note that you have to handle user input: you are assuming that he will insert a string such `"NN/NN/NNNN"`. What if he insert `"NN/NN"`? or `"this/will/crash"`?

Answer (score 1):

Given your current design, you could do it like this:

```
try
{
    Date date = new Date(day, month, year);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", date.Day, date.Month, date.Year);
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Note that reinventing the wheel isn't necessary (unless you're intentionally experimenting)... using the correct built-in .NET constructs (like `TryParseExact` instead of throwing and catching exceptions) will save you a lot of trouble:

```
Console.WriteLine("please enter date as dd/MM/yyyy");

DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Correct date: {0}", date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid date!");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: How can I do different formats within my design? e.g. MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: I want two formats of input so "dd/MM/yyyy and "MM/dd/yyyy" and I also want this for my outputs

Comment: Thats very true what if I want a format of input without the "/" and with the "/"?